# Why doesn't non doctrine-mapped ArrayCollection get initialized?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, arraycollection

My Setup is a Symfony 3.4 App with the typical '`ManyToMany`'-Relation with additional fields, something like this:

```
Entity Article
Entity Specialty
Entity ArticleSpecialtyRelation
```

In a `Form` for an `Article` i wanted it to look like as if it were a `ManyToMany`-Relation rendered as an `EntityType` with `multiple=true` and `expanded=true`, so all entries of `Specialty` are rendered as checkboxes.

To achieve that i created a non orm-mapped property `specialties` that is an ArrayCollection, gets initialized in the Constructor and has a Getter, Adder and Remover.

```
 /**
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection;
 * 
 */
 protected $specialties;

public function __construct()
    {
        $this->specialties = new ArrayCollection();
    }

 /**
 * @return Collection|Specialty[]
 */
public function getSpecialties()
{
    return $this->specialties;
}

/**
 * @param Specialty $specialties
 */
public function addSpecialties(Specialty $specialties)
{
    $this->specialties->add($specialties);

}

/**
 * @param Specialty $specialties
 */
public function removeSpecialties(Specialty $specialties)
{
    $this->specialties->removeElement($specialties);
}
```

This property is used to render the `Specialty` Entity as checkboxes:

```
add('specialties', EntityType::class,array(
            'class' => Specialty::class,
            'expanded'=>true,
            'multiple'=>true,
            'label'=>'Specialties',
            'required' => false,
            'mapped'=>true,
        ));
```

To populate it with the data from `SpecialtyRelation` i added a `PreSetData Formevent`:

```
 $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $article = $event->getData();

            if ($article instanceof Article) {
                $form->get('specialties')->setData($article->getUsedSpecialties());
            }
        });
```

The used Getter of `$artikel` just iterates over `$article->getArtikelSpecialties` and returns a collection of `Specialty`.

It all works until the submit. Because the formfield is `mapped=true`, somewhere in `handleRequest($form)` where the entity is hydrated with the form data, it explodes when the Adder for `$specialty` is called:

**`Call to a member function add() on null`**

Because as i just learned, the `Constructor` is never called by Doctrine and obviously initializes all ORM-`ArrayCollections` but not the `ArrayCollection` for the non-mapped property `specialties` -

Of course I can check if the `ArrayCollection` is initialized in the Adder and Remover and initialize it there if it is null, but that just feels a bit hacky in a already at least hacky-felt setup and i am wondering if my setup is completely stupid, especially since i didn't find anybody trying to do that (or getting problems with that) on here or elsewhere.

Is there a better solution to this or should i just check the `ArrayCollection` in Adder and Remover and live happily ever after? 
Also, just curious, is there any other way to initialize the `ArrayCollection`?

P.S. If there are typos in the names it's because i translated the names into english.

**Partial Stacktrace**

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a
>   member function add() on null
>
> at src/Test/Bundle/TestBundle/Entity/Article.php:312   at
>   Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\Article->addSpecialties(object(Specialty))
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php:674)
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor->writeCollection(array(object(Article),
>   object(Article)), 'specialties', object(ArrayCollection),
>   'addSpecialties', 'removeSpecialties')
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php:622)
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor->writeProperty(array(object(Article),
>   object(Article)), 'specialties', object(ArrayCollection))
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php:216)
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor->setValue(object(Article),
>   object(PropertyPath), object(ArrayCollection))
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php:86)
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper->mapFormsToData(object(RecursiveIteratorIterator),
>   object(Article))
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php:636)   at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->submit(array(), true)
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php:580)

Comment: `it explodes when the Adder for $specialty is called` mind that by phrasing it like that your question could also auto-implode. Rather add the exception trace in your question.

Comment: Thanks! I do mind of course :) and have added the exact error and a partial stacktrace with the interesting bit.